# Given the package, class, function(s), and parameters in Strings, how can I dynamically invoke a function in AS3?

Tags: string, actionscript-3, function, dynamic, singleton

I need to send requests between two separate `.swf`s, `A` and `B`.  I have an `interface`, `IRequest` with the following methods:

```
public interface IRequest {
    function get packagePath():String;
    function get className():String;
    function get functions():Vector.<String>;
    function get parameters():Array;
    function execute():void;
}
```

I implement it in a class, `Request`.  One can create a new request as follows:
`RequestManager.addToQueue(new Request("com.myPackage", "MyClass", "instance.method1.method2", "parameter"));`

This creates a new `Request` with a supplied `package`, `class`-name, `list of functions` and `parameters`.

Things become complicated with a chain of `function`-calls and deciding if a `function` is actually a `function` or `property` (`public function getMyThing():Object` vs `public function get myThing():Object`).

For example, things are simple enough if the desired `Request` is `new Request("com.myPackage", "MyClass", "getInstance", "");`

Invoking that method is as simple as:

```
var theClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(packagePath + "." + className) as Class;
var theInstance:Object = theClass[functions[0]](); // Invokes com.myPackage.MyClass.getInstance()
```

However, this won't work if `getInstance` is a `property`/`getter`. Also, if there are numerous method calls, I'm not sure how to invoke the chain in one call.  For example:

```
var theClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(packagePath + "." + className) as Class;
var object = theClass[functions[0]]()[functions[1]()[functions[2](); // Invokes com.myPackage.MyClass.firstMethod.secondMethod.thirdMethod()
```

However, I need to do this dynamically, and I don't see an easy way of dynamically chaining those `[`, `]`.

If anyone knows a nice way for me to be able to invoke methods from a `String`, that's essentially what I want to do.

`"com.myPackage.MyClass.firstMethod.secondMethod.thirdMethod()", parameters`

Thanks for the help,

Comment: The last string you posted "com.myPackage..." is syntactically ambiguous, there is no way to tell where the package/class name ends and the list of functions to call begins, further it's ambiguous whether you would need to pass the results of one function as an argument to the next.  Some things to check out: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Function.html <-- call and apply methods on Function may be helpful http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType() <-- returns XML should discern accessors/funcs.

Comment: Great point on the ambiguity.  I think I have a few restrictions I can impose to clear that up.

I'll take a look at the documentation to see if I can figure anything out.

Answer (score 1):

I think doing a check whether that argument actually holds a function before invoking it would help.

```
var theClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(packagePath + "." + className) as Class;

if(theClass[functions[0]] is Function){
    var theInstance:Object = theClass[functions[0]](); // Invokes com.myPackage.MyClass.getInstance()
}
```